# Автосоздание билдера IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Можно ли как нить создать автоматически билдер класс, что б не писать все это ручками? Вот такое нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Билдер чего? Билдеры обычно применяются для сборки сложных объектов

Comment: @Виктор в которых много полей да?

Comment: вы постарайтесь конкретно объяснить, что вы понимаете под билдером

Comment: добавл скрин, что б было понятней

Comment: это обычный класс. методы id и name называются сеттерами. По стандартам они не должны ничего возвращать, т.к. это методы объекта.   ИДЕЯ поддерживает автоматическую генерацию сеттеров и геттеров. Alt-insert -> Getters and Setters. Там же можно сгенерировать конструктор. Ну а метод build это типичный геттер для переменной test. Посмотрите видео \ почитайте про геттеры и сеттеры, там ответ на ваши вопросы. Потом приходите с новыми - более конкретными =)

Comment: Я вам про круглое, вы мне про квадратное. Это в данном конкретном примере можно обойтись геттером сеттером и конструктором. А что если у класса 20 полей? При создании такого объекта через конструктор можно и запутаться. Мне не нужны сеттеры и геттеры. Мне нужен БИЛДЕР. И я спросил про автоматическую генерацию именно БИЛДЕРА. Как сеттеры делать я знаю.

Comment: ну стоило сразу описать, что у вас большой класс и вам надо собирать его по кусочкам. Не правильно вас понял.

Answer (score 2):

Есть замечательный проект lombok([Сайт](https://projectlombok.org), [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok)). Нужно лишь установить плагин в IDE и подключить зависимость в мавене и можно будет забыть о геттерах/сеттерах, билдерах, т.д - нужно будет просто поставить соответствующую аннотацию над классом(@Getter, @Setter, @Builder, ...)
Все аннотации заменяются сгенерированным кодом на этапе компиляции, а благодаря плагину в IDE все подсказки продолжают работать так, будто у вас уже есть эти методы. Плюс можно через меню(ПКМ по классу -> Delombok) заменить аннотации сгенерированным кодом.

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю что это такое

Comment: Блин, крутая штука =) Читал что Котлин на что-то похожее уже перешел.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй нажми правой кнопкой мыши на package. New -> Edit File Templates.
И там нажми плюс создай свой шаблон.

Upd.

Оно ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что-то вроде того как создаются геттэры, сеттэры, конструкторы, такого нет?

Comment: alt + insert там появится панель, для создания сеттеров, геттеров, конструкторов, переопределения методов, делегаты и т.д.

Comment: да, но билдера там нету

Comment: создаешь поля, нажимаешь alt + ins и все там есть, что тебе вообще нужно, я тебе ответил, как создается определенный шаблон класса.

Comment: шаблон это не то что мне нужно. Мне нужно создать БИЛДЕР класса. Это такая штука, которая собирает объект

Comment: Изучи хотя бы паттерны. Я тебе посоветовал реализацию, если ты не понимаешь этого, тогда увы

Comment: Возможно я не понимаю как получить доступ к определенным полям класса, что бы создать шаблон

Comment: Ты хочешь, реализовать шаблон билдер ? Или тебе нужно просто ввести поля и чтобы для каждого поля создавался get,set и для них constructor?

Comment: Не просто шаблон, а сам билдер. Или возможно я не понял что вы имеете ввиду под словом шаблон. Мне не нужно просто две строки типа с названием класса и фигурными скобками. Нужен билдер со всеми методами, который собирает объект определенного класса.

Comment: Под шаблоном я подразумеваю паттерн программирования. Я добавлю сейчас в ответ скриншот. Посмотрите

Comment: Если под шаблоном вы понимаете паттерн программирования, тогда я не так понял. Я думал что вы говорите о шаблоне создания класса. Да, но на скрине, вы создаёте конструктор, верно?

Comment: Нет я показываю, вам это нужно или нет ? Если вам нужен паттерн билдер. Тогда вы просто создайте шаблон в idea.

Comment: Мне нужно это, но нужно что бы создавался паттерн билдер. Шаблом в idea это New -> Edit File Templates

Comment: Так напишите его сами один раз и он будет создаваться всегда. Там вроде есть пример, синглтона и т.д.

Comment: Если создание шаблона это New -> Edit File Templates и там создать свой, то как там получить доступ к полям класса?